# Best way to resolve OutOfMemoryException? (C#)

Tags: c#, memory, telerik

I'm using C#, .Net 4.6.x, and the Telerik controls for WinForms in Visual Studio 2017 RC. The application consists of a "main" window that uses a RadRibbon and a RadPageView.  The RadPageView is dynamically populated with pages based on a search form which is the first page, or by a user requesting a new blank form.  The other pages are inherited from RadPageViewPage and have an additional property called "TQC".  TQC refers to a custom control that loads on the page.

The TQC has several dropdownlists and text areas in RadPageViewPages that are all contained in a RadPageView control within the TQC object.  It doesn't bind any data to its controls until its RPVP (the class inheriting RadPageViewPage) is Selected. One of the dropdownlists contains 200 or so entries when it's populated (a list of accounts).

The problem I've run into is that when the outer RadPageView Remove()s a page, the memory taken by that page isn't freeing up, to the order of a couple hundred megabytes.  This is problematic, as the target machines have between 4GB and 8GB of RAM. I tried setting the data objects that populate the controls to null as part of the closing event, but nothing changed. I also tried explicitly calling the Dispose() method on all descendants of the RadPageViewPage as below:

```
private void rpvQtabs_PageRemoved(object sender, RadPageViewEventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (TQC c in e.Page.Controls)
        {                
            foreach (Control ca in c.Controls)
            {
                foreach (Control cac in ca.Controls)
                {
                    cac.Dispose();
                }
                ca.Dispose();
            }
            c.Dispose();
        }
        e.Page.Dispose();           
    }
```

I'm still getting a crazy huge memory leak, and if more than 5 tabs are viewed by the user (even if they close the page), an OutOfMemoryException is soon to follow.  I tried attaching the Performance Profiler, but it crashes on the attempt.  VS 2015 isn't an option at the moment.  How can I ensure that the pages are disposed properly, or reduce the memory footprint on the extremely large dropdownlists?  This is our first foray into using Telerik.

In response to questions in the comments:

The object that throws the error is usually relatively random and depends on which accounts are loaded.  It's not anything infinitely recursive. This is how the control's is originally loaded (using a special connection class):

```
public static List<Account> List(bool includeDefaults = true)
    {
        //search
        var rs = new List<Account>();
        string q = "select distinct r.ID, r.name from db.addressbook r";
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (var cmd = new CustomConnectionClass())
        {
            cmd.Safety.Off();
            dt = cmd.ExecuteDirectQuery(q);
        }

        foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
        {
            var a = new Account();
            a.ID = long.Parse(r[0].ToString());
            a.Name = r[1].ToString();
            rs.Add(a);
        }
        rs = rs.OrderBy(t => t.ID).ToList();
        var n = new Account();
        n.ID = 0;
        n.Name = "Generic Account";
        var o = new Account();
        o.ID = 999999;
        o.Name = n.Name;
        rs.InsertRange(0, new Account[] { n, o });
        return rs;

    }
```

Comment: How many item do you have in then DropDownList? What are the item ? A complexe object or just an id + value ?

Comment: It's bound to an IEnumerable<Account>.  It contains 16 properties, most of which are not loaded when just generating the list.  The only two that are populated, actually, are the ID number and the name, which are concatenated to make the display text in the dropdown via the ToString() method.  The IEnumerable is actually created when the application loads as part of the main form, but is accessed by child objects to bind to these controls.

Comment: I have just Load a DropDownList with 100000 row Datatable with out any issue .. Datatable contains 9 columns all set. So 200Entry *16 Properties should not be an issue.

Comment: Can you tell me what element is causing the Error ? So I can try to make a simple test project to find a work around.

Comment: The object that throws the error is usually relatively random and depends on which accounts are loaded.  It's not anything infinitely recursive. This is how the control is loaded:

Comment: I fail to reproduce your issue with less that 100000 contact in the list. Your best bet is to ask directly to Telerik with a sample project.

Comment: I was able to nail down that this is tied to how Telerik loads its themes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation, I was able to sort out that this involves how Telerik loads its themes and controls. Making all datasources for the dropdownlists `static` reduced the footprint a bit, but the thememanager and themes for the controls within each tab were loaded as new each time.  By design, they aren't necessarily disposed when the control is closed and disposed.  The design of the UI will have to be re-worked to prevent users from running out of memory.  The problem goes away if the same design is incorporated using standard WinForms.

Comment: You should make a report bug to telerik about this. You can win a nice discount on your next licence.